# SQL Server : Search Tags Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure to display a single tag (paged) in MSSQL2012.

There are 3 tables, StockItems, Files and Tags
Each StockItem can have more tags and one image file.

How can I modify this stored procedure to return a search of multitple tags by returning the related stockitem and image file?

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetTagPaged](
    @KeyWordFilter varchar(50),
    @PageNumber int = 1)          
as
begin
    declare @PageSize int = 50
    declare @FirstRow int
    declare @LastRow int
    declare @TotalRows int

    SELECT      
        @FirstRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1,
        @LastRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + @PageSize;

   SELECT 
       @TotalRows = COUNT(*) 
   FROM
       [StockItem] q 
   INNER JOIN 
       [Tags] k ON q.id = k.StockItemId 
   INNER JOIN 
       [Files] qi ON q.Id = qi.ItemId 
   WHERE
       k.Keyword = @KeyWordFilter;

with Results as
(                  
      SELECT            
         q.*, qi.FileName
         , ROW_NUMBER() over (Order By q.Rating DESC) as Instance_Count
         , @TotalRows as the_Count
      FROM 
         [StockItem] q
      INNER JOIN 
         [Tags] k ON q.id = k.StockItemId
      INNER JOIN 
         [Files] qi ON q.Id = qi.ItemId
      WHERE 
         k.Keyword = @KeyWordFilter
    )            
    select *
    from results
    where Instance_Count between @FirstRow and @LastRow
    order by Instance_Count asc                  
end
```

Comment: Which version of ms sql?

Comment: Your alias for StockItems is q, tags is k and files is qi? Are you trying to make it more complex with those aliases...

Comment: Also, at least to me it's unclear what you exactly want to do, and what problem you faced doing it

Comment: mssql 2012, I will update the question